# Using phpword extension in yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

Creating word documents using php word in Yii2.

Can any one help me how to use and install phpword in Yii2. I am using Yii2 advanced project

Comment: Are you trying to use m0zart89/yii2-phpword ?? or wnyother extension ??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have composer.phar file.

run

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist m0zart89/yii2-phpword "*"
```

or add

```
"m0zart89/yii2-phpword": "*"
```

to the require section of your composer.json file.

Once the extension is installed, simply use it in your code by :

```
<?= \m0zart89\\phpword\\AutoloadExample::widget(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package m0zart89/yii2-phpword * is satisfiable by m
>   ii2-phpword[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or mi
>   bility.